# Kruskal-Katona for homocyclic groups?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

I need a version of the Kruskal-Katona theorem (better still, of the Lovasz "approximate" version thereof) for the elementary abelian / homocyclic groups, in the following spirit:

> What is the smallest possible size of the shadow of a subset $A\subset(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^n$ given the size $N:=|A|$ and the common weight $k$ of  all the elements of $A$?

Here the weight of an element
  $$ x_1e_1+\dotsb+x_n e_n,\quad 0\le x_i<m $$
is the number of non-zero coefficients among $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$, and the shadow of $A$ is the set of all those group elements 
of weight $k-1$ lying below an element of $A$.

(I assume that $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^n$ is equipped with a fixed generating subset $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$, and I say that $y_1e_1+\dotsb+y_ne_n$ lies below $x_1e_1+\dotsb+x_n e_n$, with $x_i,y_i\in[0,m-1]$, if $y_i\le x_i$ for each $i=1,\dotsc n$.)

Is anything of this sort known? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, the group structure on $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is not important at all?

Comment: Do we really sum up elements of this group? Or we may consider any set of cardinality $m$ instead?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^n$ is a group under addition, what is wrong with adding its elements? Evidently, I am missing something....

Comment: Nothing is wrong, but is not the following question the same? "Given alphabet $M$ with $m$ letters, one of them is $0$. Consider a set $A$ of length $n$ over this alphabet, each word in $A$ has exactly $n-k$ letters 0. Shadow consists of all words obtained from some word in $A$ by replacing some non-0 letter to 0.  Given $N=|A|$, find minimal possible size of a shadow."

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: this is not exactly the same. To form the shadow, you are allowed to replace any letter with a "smaller non-zero letter" - and, in addition, exactly one non-zero letter is to be replaced by the zero letter.

Comment: What do you mean by "smaller" for residues modulo $m$? They are ordered from 0 to $m-1$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: yes. This was somewhat implicit in my question, I made it more explicit now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32842/discussion-between-seva-and-fedor-petrov).

Comment: Very nice question. I am quite sure some higher alphabets versions of Kruskal-Katona are known but I don't remember. In fact it seems that this is a Kruskal-Katona theorem for products of paths.