# Kruskal-Katona for multisets?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

Following Fedor Petrov's remarks, here is a "set-theoretic version" of the 
[question I asked a while ago](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225754/kruskal-katona-for-homocyclic-groups).

---

For integer $n\ge 1$, denote by $\mathcal M_n$ the family of all (finite)
multisets with the ground set $[n]$. Considering the multisets from 
$\mathcal M_n$ as functions from $[n]$ to the set of non-negative integers, we can speak about the support ${\rm supp} A\subseteq[n]$ of a multiset
$A\in\mathcal M_n$; thus, $|{\rm supp} A|$ is just the number of distinct
elements of the ground set contained in $A$. Also, define a partial order on
$\mathcal M_n$ writing $A\preceq B$ if $A(i)\le B(i)$ for each $i\in[n]$; that is, if the multiplicity of every $i\in[n]$ in $A$ does not exceed its multiplicity in $B$.

The *shadow* of a multiset $A\in\mathcal M_n$ is the set of all those
$A'\in\mathcal M_n$ with $|{\rm supp} A'|=|{\rm supp} A|-1$ and $A'\preceq
A$; the shadow of a family $\mathcal A\subseteq \mathcal M_n$ is the set of
all those $A'\in\mathcal M_n$ which are the shadow of at least one multiset
$A\in\mathcal A$.

> Fix now $k\in[1,n]$ and $N\ge 1$, and suppose that
>    $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal M_n$ is a family of $N$ multisets with $|{\rm supp} A|=k$ for each $A\in\mathcal
> A$. How small can the shadow of $\mathcal A$ be (in terms of $N,k$, and $n$)?

---

It should be possible to work this out, but I wonder whether this problem has already been studied. I am aware of [the paper by Bekmetjev, Brightwell, Czygrinow, and Hurlbert](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406068), but they seem to treat the things a little differently.